# What is more used, Left or Right shift?

Tags: cpu

Oki, so I'm building a 16 bit CPU in logisim and I finished the adder and the subtracter and the NAND gate functions. Then I was like hmmm, right or left carry?
Left is used for multiplication, right for division but since im not good at RISC coding (cause yah, its gonna have RISC ISA) I might not implement it also it will take many more cycles. While I can make multiplication and not division I think I should go with the left carry but im not sure? Which one shall I use, or shall I use both? Thx

Comment: A single bit shift is pretty simple. Many modern CPUs have barrel shifters.

Comment: You are asking *which operation is indispensable in a minimum instruction set*, right? You might edit your question title, so people do better understand (sorry, I might be dull sometimes). You should also indicate how much performance you are willing to sacrifice.

Answer (score 2):

Your CPU should have five different single-bit shifts to make life easy to programmers.

- shift left into carry, fill LSB with zero. This is usually called "shift left"
- shift right into carry, fill MSB with zero. This is usually called "logical shift right"
- shift right into carry, leave MSB intact (meaning, the MSB is doubled into the adjacent position). This is usually called "arithmetic shift right". You need this for 2-complement numbers.
- rotate left through carry. Same as shift left, but the LSB is filled with the old value of the carry flag.
- rotate right through carry. Same as logical shift right, but the MSB is filled with the old value of the carry flag.

The rotate instructions are useful when cascading shifts over multiple words.

Comment: Whoah thx brah :D

Comment: but hey brah, is not gonna have an assembler/compiler, just an EEPROM so basically U gotta know the CPU before coding it. Ill use both :)

Comment: I'll just use a barrel shifter, like ARM1

Comment: @JesseCarter Cripes. If you will include a fully combinatorial barrel shifter (which I love to have), you might was as well also include the ability to do a barrel shift with a count which places the leading bit at the high order position. Or shift some number of bits. (Normalization and denormalization.) This is incredibly useful for fast floating point support without needing all that nasty added FP hardware or associated power consumption and real estate. Examine the Analog Devices ADSP-21xx core.